ssh using private key still force me to insert password

I am trying to create a ceph cluster using the ceph-ansible and encountered something I don't understand:

When I put the output of vagrant ssh-config in my ~/.ssh/config, I am able to connect to my VM:  
Host osd2
  HostName 127.0.0.1
  User vagrant
  Port 2207
  UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
  StrictHostKeyChecking no
  PasswordAuthentication no
  IdentityFile /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519
  IdentityFile /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.rsa
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  LogLevel FATAL
  ForwardAgent yes
  PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes +ssh-rsa
  HostKeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa



However, when I try to connect to my VM using ssh, I get prompted to enter a password, and am curious to know why:  
$ ssh -i /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519 -F /dev/null -o IdentitiesOnly=yes  vagrant@127.0.0.1 -p 2207






ACLs:  Client:
-rw------- 1 hatef hatef 411 Jul  9 16:03 /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519

Server:
-rw-------. 1 vagrant root 409 Oct  6  2015 authorized_keys



sshd_config:
# $OpenBSD: sshd_config,v 1.93 2014/01/10 05:59:19 djm Exp $

HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV

AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication yes
ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
UsePAM yes

GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPICleanupCredentials no

X11Forwarding yes

UsePrivilegeSeparation sandbox

AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS

Subsystem  sftp  /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server

UseDNS no
GSSAPIAuthentication no



Client SSH Log:
OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4, OpenSSL 3.0.13 30 Jan 2024

debug1: Reading configuration data /dev/null
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 127.0.0.1 is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: channel_clear_timeouts: clearing
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 2207.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519 type 3
debug1: identity file /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.6p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu13.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000002
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 127.0.0.1:2207 as 'vagrant'
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2207

debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:2207
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: have matching best-preference key type ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com, using HostkeyAlgorithms verbatim
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: sntrup761x25519-sha512@openssh.com,curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c,kex-strict-c-v00@openssh.com
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:3NyH9z5a+mBAg9RbyQRzfWoPJ6x0/lOLWRj3IYiI8SE
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2207
debug3: put_host_port: [127.0.0.1]:2207

debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file /home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [127.0.0.1]:2207
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: Host '[127.0.0.1]:2207' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hatef/.ssh/known_hosts:7
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: ssh_set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51

debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
debug1: get_agent_identities: bound agent to hostkey
debug1: get_agent_identities: agent returned 1 keys
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:WkvqjnyPAeC0cbPErYiGP9vqHdgL1MqqvPdIe3lvHgI explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hatef/.vagrant.d/insecure_private_keys/vagrant.key.ed25519 ED25519 SHA256:WkvqjnyPAeC0cbPErYiGP9vqHdgL1MqqvPdIe3lvHgI explicit
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password




In order to diagnose what is happening, you will have to provide the verbose logs from both the client and server, the SSH server configuration, the ACL for the keys from both the server and client.  All this information should be added as an edit to your question

@Ramhound I edited the question. if something else is required please mention it.

@badger Please never screenshot terminal output - instead, please copy/paste into a code box. Also, sshd_config has conflicting options enabled for GSSAPIAuthentication

@JW0914 I thought to myself it probably increases clarity of the question. and thanks for the edit

You sent the ED25519 key. The VM may require the RSA key instead.

Your verbose server log is missing that would explain why the client wasn’t able to authenticate with the keys it offered
